# cannot enable wifi on Ubuntu server 22.04 installed on macbook air 2019 with Broadcom [14e4:4488] (rev 04)

Tags: networking, server, broadcom, macbook

I am connected to the internet via ethernet cable and want to enable wifi on macbook air 2019 running ubuntu server 22.04. My pciid is as follows:

```
73:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4377b Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4488] (rev 04)
```

I went through some of the existing resources to solve this issue but did not find any instructions for broadcom 4488.

I tried installing

```
bcmwl-kernel-source
firmware-b43-installer
```

but had no luck. Any help is appreciated. Thanks much!

Edit 1: Adding relevant information:

1. uname -r gave me this
   "5.15.0-91-generic",
2. modinfo brcmfmac | grep 4488 returned nothing.

Comment: Refer to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers  I've done this exact setup. just a few weeks ago. b43-fwcutter is still active and maintained. If you get errors, post em.

Comment: Your 14e4:4488 device is covered by the driver *brcmfmac* in recent Ubuntu versions. Please check the message log: `sudo dmesg | grep brcm` I suspect that you are missing the required firmware. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried it by installing `b43-fwcutter`, `firmware-b43-installer` and `linux-installer`. I checked the blacklist config and commented `blacklist bcm43xx` as well. I tried `rfkill unblock all`. I looked for errors and checked message log using `sudo dmesg | grep brcm` and found no logs. What I am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help @chili555 and @j0h.

Comment: Please edit your question to showthe result of: `uname -r` and also: `modinfo brcmfmac | grep 4488`

Comment: "5.15.0-91-generic" The version of the *brcmfmac* driver in 5.15-xx doesn't include your device. I suggest tat you install a 6.5-xx kernel or reinstall 23.10. Then we need to install firmware.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to say I have the exact same issue with the exact same network controller [14e4:4488] (rev 04) and I have managed to fix the issue.

The following command `sudo dmesg | grep brcm` gave me this output:

```
2.420634] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    2.420663] brcmfmac 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 - > 0002)
[    2.531373] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using 
brcm/brcmfmac4377b3-pcie for chip BCM4377/4
[    2.534562] brcmfmac 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load 
for brcm/brcmfmac4377b3-pcie.apple,formosa-SPPR-u-3.1-X3.bin 
            failed with error -2
[    2.534590] brcmfmac 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load 
            for brcm/brcmfmac4377b3-pcie.apple,formosa-SPPR-u-3.1.bin 
failed with error -2
[    2.534613] brcmfmac 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load 
            for brcm/brcmfmac4377b3-pcie.apple,formosa-SPPR-u.bin failed 
            with error -2
[    2.534637] brcmfmac 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load 
            for brcm/brcmfmac4377b3-pcie.apple,formosa-SPPR.bin failed 
            with error -2
[    2.534659] brcmfmac 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load 
            for brcm/brcmfmac4377b3-pcie.apple,formosa-X3.bin failed with 
            error -2
[    2.534682] brcmfmac 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load 
            for brcm/brcmfmac4377b3-pcie.apple,formosa.bin failed with 
            error -2
[    2.534703] brcmfmac 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load 
            for brcm/brcmfmac4377b3-pcie.bin failed with error -2
[    2.534706] brcmfmac 0000:01:00.0: brcmf_pcie_setup: 
            Dongle setup failed
[    2.534720] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_fw_crashed: Firmware has 
            halted or crashed
[    2.598792] hci_bcm4377 0000:01:00.1: Unable to load 
            firmware; tried 'brcm/brcmbt4377b3-apple,formosa-u.bin' and 
            'brcm/brcmbt4377b3-apple,formosa.bin'
```

The issue on my system was the firmware. Simply download the latest release deb file [from here](https://github.com/AdityaGarg8/Apple-Firmware).

Now place this file in `/lib/firmware/brcm`. Navigate there and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i apple-firmware.deb
```

and then reboot. The issue should now be fixed.